# How to Binding request url template request with Bean?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a handler method for a RESTful url like /jobtype/{jobType}/id/{jobId} which I need to bind to a class named JobType.
The class JobType contains jobId and jobType.

How can I bind the URI template to the JobType class? I tried using @PathVariable but it is picking only the JobType and not id.

How can webDataBinder help in this scenario? I tried using @initBinder to bind the JobType class to the property editor but its not working.

```
//Request handler method code
@RequestMapping(value="/jobtype/{jobType}/id/{jobId}")
public ModelAndView fooViewWithDate(JobType jobType){
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/admin/foo");
    mav.addObject("jobType", jobType);
    return mav;
}

@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder wdb){
    wdb.registerCustomEditor(JobType.class, new JobTypePropertyEditor());
}


public class JobTypePropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {  
@Override
public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    JobType jobType = new JobType();
    jobType.setName(text);
    setValue(jobType);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments on my previous answer, this might be a solution for you.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/jobtype/{jobType}/id/{jobId}")
public ModelAndView fooViewWithDate(HttpServletRequest request) {
   LinkedHashMap map = (LinkedHashMap) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);
   JobType jobType = new JobType(map);
   ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/admin/foo");
   mav.addObject("jobType", jobType);
   return mav;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question perfectly but it looks like JobType is a name and an id so that is what you should put in the @RequestMapping. Like this:

```
//Request handler method code
@RequestMapping(value="/jobtype/{jobType}/id/{jobId}")
   public ModelAndView fooViewWithDate(@PathVariable JobType jobType, 
                                       @PathVariable int jobId){
   jobType.setId(jobId);
   ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/admin/foo");
   mav.addObject("jobType", jobType);
   return mav;
}
```

Comment: you have understood it correctly, just that my url formation is

/jobtype/{jobType}/id/{jobId} instead of /jobtype/{jobName}/{jobId}. 
But the only problem is that I don't want to use @pathVariable annotation and pass all the parameters to the method. Instead I want to instantiate JobType with {jobType},{jobId} automatically and then pass JobType object as method parameter to the handler method.

Hope this explains the situation a little better.

Comment: I've changed my example to show a way of doing it. I still uses @PathVariable but I don't think you'll even get into your custom editor without it. And I don't see how that custom editor could take two different attributes, just one (the text).

Comment: Hi Adreas, thanks for the reply. Say for instance you have a long url like jobtype/{jobType}/id/{jobId}/institute/{inst}/school/{school}/grade/{grade} then do we have to pass all the @pathVariables as method parameters? Isn't their a way to automatically bind all these parameter to the JobType bean?

Comment: It would be good if there was but I've never seen it. I don't have loads of experience with Spring MVC but I think I would have seen this in the course book or somewhere else if there was a way.

Comment: You could hack around it perhaps.
There is a hashmap available from the request with all mappings.
I'm posting that as another answer.